# connect each vertex by a 3D curve

Tags: python, scripting

From this blend file created in Python see file link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x3cjvxuWx5PHjViX3jD3HzfCwBMUxm7M/view?usp=sharing

Where a grid of vertices is created, I wish to connect each adjacent vertex in Python by this arc of circle of parametric equation:

```
x = 1/2 * sin (t)

y = 0

z = 1/2 * (cos (t) +1)

0 <= t <= pi
```

That is, adding to the script of the blend file something like:

```
import math

mesh = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new ()


for a in: range (0,3.14157):

     u = 1/2 * math.sin (a)

     v = 0

     w = 1/2 * (math.cos (a) +1)

     bm.verts.new ([u, v, w])

bm.to_mesh (mesh)

bm.free ()
```

Comment: yes I solved my question with this blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-g2YhYUY-0Kz5KXXcJx1Z8cJ0wqOgLac/view?usp=sharing